# Why nodemailer module is not working on google app engine?

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, nodemailer

I am trying to use node mailer to send emails. I don't want to use any third party software like Sendgrid, mailgun etc. Is there any way?

Answer (score 1):

By default google app engine have smtp standard ports closed to prevent abuse of email sending bots, anihow they have available an email api for Java, Python, PHP and Go, but not for Node right now, you can check the documentation over [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/mail/)